# Send data form PageVC to Firebase

Tags: swift, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uipageviewcontroller

I have a UIPageViewController with three ViewControllers. Is it possible to enter data in each VC and via the button in the last VC send all entered data to the FirebaseDatabase as one record?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I guess you could just grab the data for each viewController and send to the next viewController and once you're at the last viewController you could just POST all the data in one request.

Comment: I can do this in prepare(for segue: function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it many ways.

> Way One

Create `global` variables and store your data to them. In last VC just assemble them the way you want and send it to your firebase database.

> Way Two

You can create a `singleton` class with necessary attribute. Access the `singleton object` in every `ViewController` and stores your data, in last ViewController get you data from singleton and send it to firebase. To learn more about singleton see this [article](https://cocoacasts.com/what-is-a-singleton-and-how-to-create-one-in-swift/).

> Way three

You can make a base class of this three ViewController classes. In base class store your data. In last ViewController access the base class and make you necessary object to send into firebase.

> Way you can send data to firebase

Keep your database reference.

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!
ref = Database.database().reference()
```

In `button` click action send your data or object to firebase like below way.

```
self.ref.child("users").child(user.uid).setValue(["username": username])
```

To learn more about firebase follow the official [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write).

> Note: The problem you have can solve in different way. I just listed down some way here. Hope it helps you.